# IObservable<T> using linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, system.reactive

Why is `IObservable<T>` not an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`, but I can using LINQ queries? Is `IObservable` a special type ?

I used to think only Linq query IEnumerable or IQueryable , but it is not. The following code example：

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Rx_Test1
{
    public static class IMyClassExtension
    {

        public static MyClass<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this MyClass<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public static MyClass<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this MyClass<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
    public class MyClass<T>
    {

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myclass = new MyClass<int>();
            var q = from m in myclass 
                    select m;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An object implementing `IObservable` can also implement other interfaces, like `IQuerable`. Which *conrete* object are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LINQ query comprehensions work over anything that implements the corresponding Select/Where/etc. methods that the compiler can translate to. It isn't limited to specific interfaces. This is similar to how you can foreach over an object that doesn't implement IEnumerable, but contains a GetEnumerator and MoveNext/Current methods. Effectively LINQ expressions are duck typed by the compiler. This also explains why you can use some LINQ expressions over IObservable but not all (orderby is intentionally excluded).

Answer (score 2):

> Why does `IObservable` not implement `IEnumerable` or `IQuerable`

Because `IObservable` does not *necessarily* represent a *collection* - it could be a single object that pushes change events.

> But i can using Linq query ?

The [`Observable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) class implements Linq-like operators for the `IObservable` interface. I don't know what it does if the underlying type is not a collection, but my guess is it will either treat it as a single-item collection or throw an exception.

Comment: `IObservable<>` does absolutely represent a collection. It is 100% analogous with `IEnumerable<>`. So either they both represent a collection or neither of them do.

Comment: @Enigmativity 100% analagous? How? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx) for `IObservable<T>` makes no mention of collections.  In fact the _example_ does not use a collection as the observable type. The _extension methods_ from [`System.Reactive.Linq.Observable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable(v=vs.103).aspx) make it _look_ like `IEnumerable<T>`, but they are completely independent interfaces.

Comment: They aren't necessarily analogous, but they are duals from a lambda calculus perspective. In the same way that x/y = z is the same as x = zy, my flipping the inputs and outputs, IEnumerable equals IObservable. The good thing is that you don't have to understand the lambda calculus in order to take advantage of/use/love Rx.

Comment: @DStanley - Exactly what Jim said. Being mathematical duals means they are effectively the same thing. The best way, in my head, to think about them is that `IEnumerable<>` is an instantaneous collection and `IObservable<>` is a collection over time.

Comment: @DStanley - Take a look at this video from the creators of Rx - https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Brian-Beckman-and-Erik-Meijer-Inside-the-NET-Reactive-Framework-Rx

Comment: @Enigmativity My point is there's _nothing_ about `IObservable` that requires the underlying type to be a collection or has anything to do with enumeration.  Rx may _use_ `IObservable` (via extension methods) to observe changes to collections but that doesn't mean that `IObservable` is equivalent to `IEnumerable`.  I can implement `IObservable` to observe changes to a single instance (in fact the [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx) does exactly that.

Comment: @DStanley - I think you're wrong about that. The duality with `IEnumerable<>` means that `IObservable<>` must be a collection. The contract is that it will return zero or more values. That's just the same as `IEnumerable<>`. I think you're missing the point - the example in MSDN is returning zero or more `Location` instances. It is an observable collection of `Location` instances.

Comment: @DStanley - I think I see the issue here. Your answer said "it could be a single object that pushes change events". Well that's the same as `List<T>` - it's a single object that produces a list of `T` when enumerated over. An object that implements `IObserable<T>` is also a single object that produces a list of `T` when observed. They are both implemented by single objects that produce collections of values.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm done arguing - I think you're wrong in narrowly defining `IObservable<T>` by how Rx uses it, when the basic interface itself has absolutely zero connection to `IEnumerable` or collections in general. But I don't think we'll be able to convince each other either way.

Comment: @DStanley - The highest badge awarded for "System.Reactive" so far is silver - and I'm one of only two people to get it. I'm happy to stop arguing too, but maybe that's something worth thinking about.

Answer (score 2):

Anything can be made to work with Linq by implementing the appropriate extension methods (`Select`, `SelectMany`, `Where`, ...). This usually only makes sense when the type is a monad, though.

I recommend reading [The Marvels of Monads](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2008/01/11/the-marvels-of-monads.aspx), which has examples of implementing a custom Linq-to-your-type.

In the case of `Observable<T>`, the `Select` method gives you back an `Observable<T2>` where the items have been run through a function. So you can do things like "this observable, but all items +1" via `from x in obs select x + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

System.Reactive NuGet will allow you to use LINQ to IObservable